Ubuntu 24.04.1 autoinstall with cloud-init don't set hostname from 'meta-data' file
I need to use both user-data and meta-data files to install Ubuntu server 24.04.1. The installation is not performed in the Cloud, but on a self-hosted virtual machine. The hostname should be set based on the directive from the meta-data file. My meta-data file:
instance-id: i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu
instance-action: none
local-hostname: uls-base

In the user-data file the parameter preserve_hostname is used:
  preserve_hostname: false
  prefer_fqdn_over_hostname: false
  manage_etc_hosts: false
  create_hostname_file: true
  user-data:
    # hostname: ubuntu
    # fqdn:

The user-data file does not have a hostname parameter because it takes precedence over meta-data file. Installation is successful, but the host name after installation localhost.
As an option, I tried to include the meta-data file directives in the datastore section of the user-data file:
  datasource:
    NoCloud:
      seedfrom: None
      # fs_label: the label on filesystems to be searched for NoCloud source
      fs_label: cidata
      user-data: []
      meta-data: |
        instance-id: i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu
        instance-action: none
        local-hostname: uls-base

The result did not change. I don't find any errors related to the file in the cloud-init.log file:
2024-12-21 17:51:11,456 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud/meta-data (quiet=False)
2024-12-21 17:51:11,456 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 0 bytes from /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud/meta-data
2024-12-21 17:51:11,456 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud/user-data (quiet=False)
2024-12-21 17:51:11,456 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 0 bytes from /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud/user-data
2024-12-21 17:51:11,910 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu/user-data.txt - wb: [600] 15442 bytes
2024-12-21 17:51:11,925 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu/user-data.txt.i - wb: [600] 15777 bytes
2024-12-21 17:51:11,926 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-local/consume-user-data: reading and applying user-data
2024-12-21 17:51:11,941 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-local/consume-user-data: SUCCESS: reading and applying user-data

In the log file installer-journal.txt the md5 sum check is correct:
Dec 21 12:51:22 ubuntu-server casper-md5check[1841]: Checking ./cidata/meta-data..../cidata/meta-data: OK
Dec 21 12:51:22 ubuntu-server casper-md5check[1841]: Checking ./cidata/user-data...../cidata/user-data: OK

At the same time, cloud-init uses information from the meta file during installation, this can be seen from the cloud-init.log:
2024-12-21 17:51:11,910 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu/user-data.txt - wb: [600] 15442 bytes
2024-12-21 17:51:11,925 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu/user-data.txt.i - wb: [600] 15777 bytes

It uses the instance-id I set in the meta-data file /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-fmYmG78yLfijWeNzu/user-data.txt
The directory in the .iso file /cidata is used as a datasource for all files: user-data, meta-data and vendor-data. The use of the NoCloud datasource is specified in the grub configuration:
menuentry "Try or Autoinstall Ubuntu Server" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz quiet autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/cidata/  ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd
}

All settings and installations are performed without errors, the only problem is with setting the hostname based on the configuration from the meta-data file. Many thanks for help!

Does your user-data file contain an autoinstall key?  That is how you configure autoinstall.

Yes, sure. Without it, the Ubuntu installer immediately returns an error.

Can you share your entire user-data file?  The autoinstall section should contain an identity section where the hostname can be set.
